# Access: Query Join on Alias field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to Join an alias field with a function in a query. Is this possible in MS Access?

```
SELECT Mid([StockNum],1,9) AS StockTrim
FROM POs LEFT JOIN [STOCK DICTIONARY] 
    ON POs.[StockTrim] = [STOCK DICTIONARY].[Stock]
GROUP BY Mid([StockNum],1,9), [STOCK DICTIONARY].Stock
HAVING ((([STOCK DICTIONARY].Stock) Is Null));
```

In this example, I am trying to join on the calculated field **StrockTrim**, but Access brings up the "Enter Parameter Value" input box for POs.StockTrim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes you can use the alias in a query, sometimes not.  In your case, the following should work (I also cleaned up your GROUP BY/HAVING field to a more appropriate WHERE clause):

```
SELECT Mid([StockNum],1,9) AS StockTrim
FROM POs LEFT JOIN [STOCK DICTIONARY] 
  ON Mid(POs.[StockNum],1,9) = [STOCK DICTIONARY].[Stock]
WHERE [STOCK DICTIONARY].Stock Is Null
GROUP BY Mid([StockNum],1,9)
```

---

Understanding when you can use an alias in an Access query and when you cannot is a bit of dark art.  Generally speaking, you may use an alias if it occurs later in the query plan than it first appears.  For instance, you could use:

```
SELECT Mid([StockNum],1,9) AS StockTrim, "Trim #:" & StockTrim AS StockTrimNumber
```

The StockTrimNumber field, which occurs later in that sample SELECT clause than the StockTrim calculated field, can use the StockTrim calculated field in its own field definition.

In your situation, the join occurs before any of the fields are calculated or returned, so you need to repeat the field definition in your JOIN clause.

Likewise, if you wanted to filter based on your calculated field you would need to use the field definition itself (e.g., `WHERE Mid([StockNum],1,9) LIKE "???XYZ???"`) but using the alias alone would fail (e.g., `WHERE StockTrim Like "???XYZ???"`).

Comment: I got a Syntax error: `(missing operator) in query expression "Mid([StockNum],1,9) Where [STOCK DICTIONARY].Stock Is Null"`. If I change `Where` to `Having`, I get the message: `You tried to execute a query that does not include the expression '[STOCK DICTIONARY].Stock Is Null' as part of an aggregate function.`

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up the order of the WHERE and GROUP BY clauses.  I updated my answer.  Please try that and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Since you accepted mwolfe02's great answer, I hope the problem is solved.  I want to point out that since `StockTrim` is an immediate construct, rather than a field in `POs`, you may have trouble with:

```
ON POs.[StockTrim] = [STOCK DICTIONARY].[Stock]
```

You may have success with:

```
ON [StockTrim] = [STOCK DICTIONARY].[Stock]
```

That would assume there is no field named `StockTrim` in `STOCK DICTIONARY`.

Just an aside -- you'll be better off in Access if you avoid all use of spaces in names for objects, including tables and queries.  `STOCK DICTIONARY` will work better as `STOCK_DICTIONARY`, for example.